# Can I do the following in c++

Tags: c++

I have two classes namely X and Y ;

```
       X                                  Y 

    foo ( )                           bar ( )
```

Y only uses foo function in the X classes. Can I do the following in c++ ?

```
friend bool Y :: bar ( X & (X :: foo) )
```

That is `Y` has a permisson only reaching `foo` function of the `X` **object**?

EDIT : Is `X & (X :: foo)` usage correct ?

Comment: What you're asking is unclear, and the title is poorly worded. Try fixing up the post.

Comment: So you want X::foo only to be accessible from Y::bar?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you question correctly, you want something like this:

```
class X;

class Y {
public:
    void bar(X& x);
    void baz(X& x);
};

class X {
    void foo() { }
    friend void Y::bar(X& x);
};

void Y::bar(X& x)
{
    x.foo();
}

void Y::baz(X&)
{
    // the following would be an error
    // baz wasn't befriended with X
    // x.foo();
}

int main()
{
    X x;
    Y y;
    y.bar(x);
}
```

Note the order of declarations and definitions, you need it like this so you can actually make something useful with `X` inside `Y::bar()`.

If fail to think of a case where this would be a good idea to do, though. If you fell you only need to befriend "parts" of your classes, then maybe your classes are having too many responsibilities.

Comment: If you `X& x`, you can reach all private data of X. This is awkward

Comment: OP didn't ask how awkard it is, just whether it's possible :) I agree, though.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot.  But you can do the following:

```
class X_foo_friend;

class X
{
    void foo();
    friend class X_foo_friend;
};

class Y
{
    X x;
public:
    void bar();
};

class X_foo_friend
{
    static void foo(X& x);
    friend void Y::bar();
};

void X::foo() {};
void X_foo_friend::foo(X & x) { x.foo(); }

void Y::bar()
{
    X_foo_friend::foo(x);
}
```

IMO, this is rather silly.  I mean, you're the one designing both X and Y, so you could simply restrict your usage in Y of X's functions.

Answer (score 0):

I would possibly explore on the lines of an intermediate proxy using ADL concept. This is of course a partial implementation showing the concept.

```
namespace XNProxy {
    class XNP;
}

namespace XN
{
    using XNProxy::XNP;

    class X {
        friend void f(X *);
    private:
        void foo() { };
    };

    void f(X* p) {
        X x;
        x.foo();
    }
}

namespace XNProxy 
{
    class XNP { };
    using XN::X;
    void f(XNP *) {
        f((XN::X *)nullptr);
    }
};

namespace YN
{
    class Y {
    public:
        void bar() { 
            XNProxy::XNP x;
            f((XNProxy::XNP*)nullptr);
        }
    };
}

int main() {
    YN::Y y;
    y.bar();
}
```